# Firebase Typescript Typings not working after V8.0.0

Tags: typescript, firebase

I'm facing a very similar problem as this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4303) and I can't understand how can I fix it and why the types are being exported as const from firebase sdk.

The code that reexports firebase types is the following:

```js
import * as firebase from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing'

export type Firestore = firebase.firestore.Firestore;
export type FirestoreDocReference = firebase.firestore.Firestore;
```

I just want to re-export firestore types so I can declare my functions signature with typed return:

```js
function getFirestore(auth?: any): Firestore
```

Reading the SDK source code I notice that firestore is being exported as follows:

```js
declare const firestore: typeof firebase.firestore, database: typeof firebase.database;
export { firestore, database };
```

It is exported as a const, not a type. How can I workaround this? And why they are using const instead of type here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `declare const firestore: typeof firebase.firestore`, they've essentially declared that `firestore` is an object, with the shape of `firebase.firestore`, not a namespace of types. If I recall correctly, exporting these namespace-objects was done this way so package crawlers like Webpack could correctly identify which modules needed to be bundled.

To prevent confusion, instead of importing `@firebase/rules-unit-testing` as `firebase` (which should be considered reserved), import it instead as `rulesUnitTesting` or similar.

```
import * as rulesUnitTesting from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
```

You may still use the `firestore` property of this to create instances of `firebase.firestore.Firestore`, however the types will not be available from this property.

If you wish to export the type `Firestore`, you would either export it from the globally defined `firebase` module, or explicitly import it and export from there.

```
import * as rulesUnitTesting from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
// firebase is now declared & loaded in the global types.
export type Firestore = firebase.default.firestore.Firestore;
```

or

```
import * as rulesUnitTesting from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
export type Firestore = firebase.firestore.Firestore;
```

or the not recommended

```
import * as firebase from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import firebaseNamespace from 'firebase/app';
export type Firestore = firebaseNamespace.firestore.Firestore;
```